# how to loop through the elements on an array of user defined list<T>?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

i have a user defined list

```
public class Level2
{
    public double price { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }

    public Level2(double price, int size)
    {
        this.price = price;
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

in my program i have this snippet which i loop through the first 10 elements

```
List<Level2> bid = new List<Level2>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i < bid.Count && bid[i].price > bid[0].price - (20 * process.tickSize))
            {
                bidString = bidString + "," + bid[i].price.ToString() + "," + bid[i].size.ToString();
            }                
        }
```

and it compile and runs fine. 
Now i need to expand my program and want to change my variable to an array type, like this:

```
 List<Level2>[] bid = new List<Level2>[5];
```

how can i change my loop, so i can loop through the first array, ie bid[0] ?

please provide some working snippet, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all bid with bid[0]

```
List<Level2>[] bid = new List<Level2>[5]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    { 
        if (i < bid[0].Count && bid[0][i].price > bid[0][0].price - (20 * process.tickSize)) 
        { 
            bidString = bidString + "," + bid[0][i].price.ToString() + "," + bid[0][i].size.ToString(); 
        }                 
    }
```

Alternatively use a different variable for the bid array

```
List<Level2>[] bidArray = new List<Level2>[5];
```

then assign bid to be the first element

```
List<Level2> bid = bidArray[0];
```

and then continue with your existing code.

Comment: thank you very much, i dont know it is so simple, but i dont want to take any risk editing without knowing it works.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use LINQ like this?

```
List<Level2>[] bidArray = new List<Level2>()[5];

List<Level2> bid = bidArray[0];
string bidstring = "";

double initialBid = (bid.ToArray())[0].price - (20 * process.tickSize);
IEnumerable<Level2> results = bid.Where( b => b.price > initialBid );

foreach( Level2 item in results ) {
    bidString += "," + item.price.ToString() + "," + item.size.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Level2>[] bid2 = new List<Level2>[5];

foreach (List<Level2> level2List in bid2)
{   
    foreach (Level2 level2Item in level2List)
    {
    }
}
```

I hope it should work fine for your case.